# Regex for matching a string starting with a pattern and not ending with a pattern

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Given a url, i have to match that the url starts with certain domain and not ends with certain  pattern.
For eg,
Given a list of urls i want to match a url that starts with `"http://www.google.com/"` or `"http://www.facebook.com/"`  and not ends with `".jpg"` and `".bmp"` and `".png"`

I tried something like

```
^(http://www\.google\.com/|http://www\.facebook\.com/).*(\.(?!png)|(?!bmp)|(?!jpg))$
```

But it doesn't seem to work.. Any Mistakes in it? Or Any alternate way?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the rest of the links will not lead to an image, though.

Answer (score 3):

Something like `(?!png)$` is, in general, pretty meaningless; it means "a position that is *not* followed by `png`, and that *is* at the end of the string", but of course the end of a string is never followed by `png` anyway, so `(?!png)$` is equivalent to just `$`. (Do you see what I mean?)

Java regexes, fortunately, support zero-width *lookbehind* assertions, so you can write:

```
^http://www\.(google|facebook)\.com.*(?<!\.(png|bmp|jpg))$
```

where `(?<!...)` means "a position that is not *preceded* by `...`". (See [the Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).)

Comment: FYI, I am using java regex

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:google|facebook)\.com\/(?!.*?\.(?:jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$).*$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/V0X6ve1iUT

#### Java Demo: http://ideone.com/TlCyTG

Comment: @Civa: Query parameter on a png file :)

Comment: i just show example that there is a chance to failed if you want exact failed example see this--> "http : // www.png.com". Statement In question "..not ends with certain pattern..." so i said you use $ instead of \b. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this is exact requirement you want

```
^(http://www\.google\.com/|http://www\.facebook\.com/)(?!.*?\.(?:jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$).*$
```